# 16.04 LTS gets hung @ startup

Tags: 16.04

My upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 LTS gets stuck and hangs on one task way too long.

The job it seems to get stuck on is
 [OK] Starting : start Samba LSB SMB/CIFS daemon (smdb).

The background IS black, but I have access to the terminal. and now through using nmcli I have my Wi-Fi connection back, but no apt.

The question that's supposed to be this duplicate is NOT the same case here. I provided much more detail, the install version and distro as well as my attempted fixes. In my comments I added updates as I tried something a bit different daily. Today I'll work w/ systemd and try that.

Comment: I used the shortkey combo Ctrl+alt+F2 to get a terminal and iwconfig showed I have a Wi-Fi connection, startx didn't work and sudo,apt-get even aptitude aren't found. Going thru the directories I do see systemctrl in the /bin, but I was unsuccessful in starting up even Unix_update service. So yeah, that's where I am now before I have to head to work and let this go for a few hours

Comment: I've added a few directories to PATH, since /bin wasn't even a part of the checklist. I do see apt in the files but still can't use it or get any graphics to load

Comment: By holding shift our escape at startup I have a few more options, namely kernel images. The newest 4.04, makes the least progress in startup. 3.20 was better getting me to the gnome background w/ status dots showing progress. However when this Acton is concluded the login returns to a text base. Failsafe graphics mode, failed in fact. There are maybe 20 kernel options each having generic, upstart and failsafe versions. Systemd is only on the 4.**. version of the kernel. So still working on it, tiny victories at a time

Comment: Pulled up Google using links 2. links2 www.Google.com. there is apparently a graphics problem as well, everything is in text

Comment: Unetbootin also can't repair the distro from a saved Ubuntu on drive or removable media. It depends on a library that has a relocation error ( same as apt ).

Comment: I had graphics and control of the mouse briefly. Then it went to the 1sr message I've noted above.

Comment: Bought a tablet, downloaded Kali Linux, now I'll try to install it on the laptop. Pretty frustrated with the whole situation